# Remove the column tendency from HTML tables

Tags: html, html-table

I'm working on designing up a table with 7 images in it that are all roughly the same size. Basically, I was wondering if there is a way (other then splitting each row into a different table) to change the HTML tendency to put everything in columns, and force it to lay it out based on rows.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2C7N/) of what it is. (I used Lorem Ipsum instead of the images) I would like the top and bottom row centered.

I know I can do this if I was to split it into three tables and set each one to have a `width:xxxpx` and `margin: 0 auto`, but would rather not do that.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure [a table is the right tool for the job](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)?

Comment: Love that site. Seriously, I normally steer really clear of tables, but thought it would be easiest in this situation. I'll see how the non-table comes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it might be better to go with multiple divs for this issue. Is it possible to do something like the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="rows">
   <div class="top">
       <img></img>
       <img></img>
   </div>
   <div class="middle">
       <img></img> 
       <img></img>
       <img></img>
   </div>
   <div class="bottom">
       <img></img>
       <img></img>
   </div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.rows{
  margin:10px;
}

.top, .bottom{
  padding-left:85px;
  padding-right:85px;
}

.top, .bottom, .middle
{
  width:520px;
}

.rows img
{
  margin: 10px;
  width:150px;
}
```

Basically, let the normal flow of images control their positioning, and instead use margins and padding to equalize the spacing.

Comment: Thanks you all for the help! @Zensar I took your suggestion but opted to use `width:66%` (and `100%` every even row) in conjunction with `margin:0 auto;` and selecting every even row with a `:nth-child(even)` pseudo class. Here's the finished product which ended up being very extensible http://dev.dropletirrigation.com/irrigation-suppliers.html

Answer (score 2):

Why do you even bother creating multiple cells per row? Just put all your images that go in one row in the same cell, next to each other.

Comment: That does work nicely. I found that I had to put divs in there to keep it centered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See the [vertical-align](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) property.